# Is a smartcard single or multi-factor authentication

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, smartcard

Since it is only ***something you have***, that makes it single factor authentication right?

Comment: Very common to use smartcard & PIN to make it multi-factor

Comment: This refocus of the question was a good idea. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factors refer to the three different modes of authentication (although there are more - geographic, time of day, etc, but they're less typically referenced)

The 3 main factors are

1) Something you have

2) Something you are

3) Something you know

You are correct that a smart card is single factor on its own - anyone with it can authenticate to the system.

It becomes multi-factor when it's paired with an element from 2 or 3. If I have a password and a smartcard, I have two factor. If I have a password and a smartcard and a fingerprint scan I have three factor.

As an aside - If I have two smart cards and a password I still have two factor. You can't use two passwords, smart cards, or two fingerprints to make two factor.

Comment: Ok. So perhaps the practice test question had a wrong answer. I know they're phasing out the SYO-401, so maybe it is becoming obsolete

Comment: IME CompTIA, which generally good, sometimes has blatantly wrong questions in their stuff.

Comment: @Adonalsium agreed, seen it lots of times